# undefined is not a function in ejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ejs

As i am trying to dive into js world, its my first attempt to encounter and learn ejs.

Now my problem is i am getting following error:

**`for(i in data.result){ 22| var intime = data.result[i].intime; undefined is not a function`**

and related code goes like following:

```
     <table >
          <thead>
            <th>Project Name</th><th>Date</th><th>Login</th><th>Logout</th><th>Time Spend</th>
          </thead> 
          <%
            var fraction = 1000 * 60 * 60;
            for(i in data.result){
                var intime = data.result[i].intime;
                var outtime = data.result[i].outtime;
                var difftime = ((outtime.getTime() - intime.getTime()) / fraction);
                var date = data.result[i].date;
          %>
                <tr>
                  <td>Ninja</td>
                  <td><%=date%></td>
                  <td><%=intime%></td>
                  <td><%=outtime%></td>
                  <td><%=difftime%></td>
                </tr>
          <%
            }
          %>
</table>
```

**My Attempt:**

As exception is saying that something is undefined and i am trying to call the function on it, so exception is raised.
So to verify this i omiited the whole table tag and added following code only;

```
 <%= JSON.stringify(data.result[0].outtime)%>   
     <br>
     <%= JSON.stringify(data.result[1])%>   
     <br>
     <%= JSON.stringify(data.result)%>
```

which resulted in

```
"14:44:45" 
{"empId":3,"projectId":1,"intime":"09:44:45","outtime":"14:44:45","date":"2014-08-05T18:30:00.000Z"} 
[{"empId":3,"projectId":1,"intime":"09:44:45","outtime":"14:44:45","date":"2014-08-04T18:30:00.000Z"},{"empId":3,"projectId":1,"intime":"09:44:45","outtime":"14:44:45","date":"2014-08-05T18:30:00.000Z"}]
```

Now i am not able to figure out what is the problem and what mistake i am making here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a *string* (`data.result[0].outtime` and presumably `data.result[0].intime` as well) as if it were a *Date* object: `((outtime.getTime() - intime.getTime()) / fraction)`

`getTime()` is not a function available for strings (thus `undefined`), so that is why you're seeing that particular error.